# concatenative inheritance two methods with same signature

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, javascript-objects

The code below prints only the event contents, how do I make that print WheatherData.value number? I am coming from java and I am used to do it this way.

```js
const Event = (time, place) => {
    var _time = time
    var _place = place

    return {
        getTime() {
            return _time
        },
        getPlace() {
            return _place
        },
        updateTime() {
            _time = new Date(Date.now())
        },
        toString() {
            return 'Time: ' + _time + '\nPlace: ' + _place
        }
    }
}

const WeatherData = (value, time, place) => {
    var _event = Event(time, place)
    var _value = value
    const getValue = () => { return _value }
    const toString = () => { return '\nValue: ' + _value + _event.toString() }
    return Object.assign({ getValue, toString }, _event)
}



const wd = WeatherData(10.1, new Date(Date.now()), 'Chisinau, Moldova')

console.log(wd.toString())

//Time: Sat Sep 18 2021 08:49:10 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
//Place: Chisinau, Moldova
// no value printed
```

Comment: What is the reason the OP wants to intermingle own `Event` methods at the level of `WeatherData`? Why not keeping the model(ing) clean by pure aggregation, thus making an `Event` type a member of a `WeatherData` type? Also the so called *"concatenative inheritance"* has not a single inheritance feature but actually does object augmentation via closure generating factory functions. Thus in order to protect data values via local scope one for every object has to implement own getter and setter functionality which does access and alter such local data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Object.assign({ getValue, toString }, _event)
```

The line above causing the problem. When you assign `_event` object to `{ getValue, toString }` object you are simply overriding `toString` method of `WeatherData` function. Instead, just return `{ getValue, toString }` from your `WeatherData` function, like below;

```
const WeatherData = (value, time, place) => {
    var _event = Event(time, place);
    var _value = value

    const getValue = () => { return _value }
    const toString = () => { return '\nValue: ' + _value + '\n' + _event.toString() }

    return { getValue, toString }
}
```

Comment: but then, the `WeatherData` object wont inherit properties from `Event`

Comment: and it breaks the concatenative inheritance

Answer (score 1):

`return Object.assign({}, _event, { getValue, setValue, toString })`

this works for me, is it the right way to do that? I overwrite the `event`'s `toString` method this way